# Given a list of 2-columns pandas dataframes, how can I take the median of the second columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a list of pandas dataframes, each with 2-columns. The first column represents an ID, and the second represents the values. How would I combine these dataframes to where values with common IDs are replaced with its median?

E.g

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'#id': [1,2,3,4], 'values_1': [1,3,4,3]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'#id': [1,2,3,5], 'values_2': [2,5,7,6]})
df_3 = pd.DataFrame({'#id': [1,2,4,5], 'values_3': [5,6,7,8]})
```

I would like the resulting new dataframe to be:

```
answer = pd.DataFrame({'#id': [1,2,3,4,5], 'values': [2,5,5.5,5,7]})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge all df's into one df. Then group by id and calculate the median of each group.

```
df = pd.concat([df_1,df_2,df_3])
df = df.groupby('#id').agg({'values':'median'})
'''
#id values
1   2.0
2   5.0
3   5.5
4   5.0
5   7.0

'''
```

Write to excel:

```
df.reset_index().to_excel('give_an_excel_name.xlsx',index=None)
#or
df.to_excel('give_an_excel_name.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Would you also happen to know how I can write this to an excel file?
I tried

    df.to_csv('test.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False) 

but unfortunately the ids did not write to the excel file, only the values

Comment: Hey @brizzy, When you use grouby, the **#id** become the index value. If you set index false you won't be able to see them.

Comment: Thanks. If the names of the second column for each data frame is different, is there a way to customize the name of the second column of the new dataframe? Also if they have different column names what would replace 'values'?

Comment: if the column names are different, concat does not give the desired output. If each dataframe consists of two columns (id and values), you can convert them to the same names with a simple for loop. I don't know if it answers your question, if not, please detail the problem.

Comment: I've edited my question to detail the problem. Essentially if I have dataframes with different column names, is there a way to combine them similar to your answer above?

Comment: okey, will all dataframes be two columns (id, values_n)?

Comment: I'm just using values_n as an example to represent different names. In reality, they will be different dates. E.g (201801, 201901....) to represent January over different years. I would like the name of the column of the new df to be 'Jan_med' to represent the median values of all january values